# When querying multiple indices, how do I use different search parameters for each respective index in algolia? (Vue Instantsearch)

Tags: vue.js, algolia, instantsearch.js, vue-instant-search

I am using Vue Instantsearch with multiple indices.

The query takes place in a `ais-search-box` component, looking through two indices simultaneously and displaying the results in an `ais-autocomplete` component.

This works well, however I can't find a way to assign each index a respective `ais-configure` component and therefore have to use the **same** filter for both indices.
As you might imagine, with both indices containing different properties, this does not work as expected.

The docs mention this:

> Since these are two dedicated indices, you can apply different parameters and widgets to the search. You can do it by passing different parameters to `ais-configure`, or mounting different widgets in each of the `ais-index` components. (source: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/ui-and-ux-patterns/multi-index-search/vue/)

It seems unclear how one would "pass different parameters to `ais-configure`"?
Could anyone please provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a github repo with an example a little further down on that same page. here's a deep link to the code in question:

https://github.com/algolia/doc-code-samples/blob/master/Vue%20InstantSearch/multi-index-hits/src/App.vue

You can nest your `ais-config` for the second search under the `ais-index` component. Something like:

```
      <ais-instant-search
        :search-client="searchClient"
        index-name="instant_search_price_desc"
      >
        <ais-search-box v-model="query" />
        <ais-configure
          :restrictSearchableAttributes="['name']"
          :hitsPerPage="8"
        />
        <ais-hits>
          <template slot="item" slot-scope="{ item }">
            <h3><ais-highlight :hit="item" attribute="name" /></h3>
            <img :src="item.image" />
          </template>
        </ais-hits>
        <hr />
        <ais-index :search-client="searchClient" index-name="instant_search">
          <ais-configure
           :restrictSearchableAttributes="['name']"
           :hitsPerPage="2"
          />
         <ais-hits>
            ...
```

Comment: Updating link for those that are late to the party (like me).

https://github.com/algolia/doc-code-samples/blob/master/vue-instantsearch/multi-index-hits/src/App.vue